Title in Shiny bslib navset bar becomes black on Shiny Server
In Shiny I'm creating a bslib dashboard with a navset bar:
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- page(
  title = "Shiny-template",
  navset_bar(
    title = "Shiny Template",
    bg = "#004646",
    nav_panel("ärenden", 
              page_sidebar(
                # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
                sidebar = sidebar(
                  sliderInput("bins",
                              "Number of bins:",
                              min = 1,
                              max = 50,
                              value = 30)
                ),
                plotOutput("distPlot")
              )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
         main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


When running it locally (RStudio Server) the title correctly becomes white:

However, we're using Shiny Server to host the application. But there the title becomes black. I'm aware this is a hard question to answer and might be caused by a number of things unrelated to Shiny. However, I'm interested to know if anyone might know what is up?
This is what it looks like on Shiny Server:

However, when hoovering over the title it becomes white (!?)

As a quick hack for now, you can set title = HTML('<span style="color:white">Shiny Template</span>') inside navset_bar(). Have you looked in the browser console if some resources are missing?

You can also try to set inverse = TRUE inside navset_bar().
